# Can't install netatalk 3 on Stretch

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-stretch, netatalk

I've got a Pi Zero running stretch and when I install netatalk with apt-get it always installs version 2.2.5. When I run apt-cache policy netatalk, it reports that as the Candidate version.

Is there a way I can install Netatalk 3?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you still using Stretch?

Comment: Why do you need v3 - basic shares etc work fine though it does have a habit of leaving hidden files all over. Speed and stability do not differ to a great extent and the old version was fine with High Sierra (moved before Catalina / Big Sur) Apple are killing AFP (it's not an option on the iPad or iPhone Files option) stage by stage - no idea about the M1 op sys support on-going so it may be worth moving to Samba in any case

Comment: Forgot to add - there are build instructions but they do not look simple and think I would want to do a fair number of trials http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/3.1/htmldocs/installation.html

Comment: My version 2 install suddenly stopped working so I figured this might be a time to upgrade. But if there's not any difference in basic functionality, I won't bother. The weird thing is that now when I reinstall version 2, I don't get any of the expected configuration files and other things that should appear in /etc/netatalk

Answer (score 0):

Move to Raspberry Pi OS (formerly known as Raspbian) Buster.

It has netatalk 3.1.x in the repo.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving to Buster breaks the XMLRPC functionality that I need, so I'd prefer to stick with Stretch.